# Quel est le sens de « mis entre parenthèses » dans ce contexte (passage du Scaphandre et le Papillon) ?

Tags: expressions, traduction, littérature

En lisant *Le Scaphandre et le Papillon* par Jean-Dominique Bauby, j'ai trouvé une phrase (parmi d'autres) que je n'ai pas très bien comprise :

> Chaque jour ramène son lot de visages connus mis entre parenthèses le temps des vacances.

Quel est le sens de  « mis entre parenthèses le temps des vacances » ?

Answer (score 5):

Si on remet la phrase dans son contexte, le sens devient clair:

> La rentrée. L’été tire à sa fin. Les nuits fraîchissent et je recommence à me blottir sous les épaisses couvertures bleues estampillées « Hôpitaux de Paris ». Chaque jour ramène son lot de visages connus mis entre parenthèses le temps des vacances : la lingère, le dentiste, le vaguemestre, une infirmière qui est devenue grand-mère d’un petit Thomas et l’homme qui en juin s’était brisé le doigt avec une barrière de lit. On retrouve ses marques, ses habitudes (...)

Le narrateur est depuis lontemps à l'hôpital. Il y a passé tout l'été, et vient maintenant la *rentrée*: le personnel de l'hôpital qui était en vacances rentre et reprend son poste. Le narrateur retrouve donc les personnes *mises entre parenthèses* pendant les vacances, c'est-à-dire temporairement absentes de son quotidien parce qu'elles étaient parties en vacances.

Chaque jour, le narrateur revoit donc les visages *connus* (= qu'il connaissait déjà avant, et qu'il reconnait) *mis entre parenthèses* (= temporairement disparus) *le temps des vacances* (=pendant les vacances).

De manière plus générale, ce sens métaphorique de *mettre entre parenthèses* n'est pas rare et signifie *mettre temporairement à l'écart ou de côté*.

On peut dire par exemple:

> J'ai décidé de *mettre ma carrière entre parenthèses* pour m'occuper de mes jeunes enfants.

Ou un exemple tiré du [*Monde*](https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2019/01/16/il-faut-mettre-le-brexit-entre-parentheses-on-ne-peut-pas-filer-vers-l-inconnu-comme-ca_5410144_3210.html):

> Il faut *mettre le Brexit entre parenthèses*.